# update two tables with one Store Procedure in SQL server?

Tags: sql

I have problem when I tried to update two tables in one Store Procedure I get the SqlException could some one help me

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK".
>   The conflict occurred in database "", table "dbo.Users", column
>   'userID'. The statement has been terminated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[CreateProject]
    @ProjectID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @ProjectName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Description NTEXT,
    @EstStartDate DATETIME,
    @EstEndDate DATETIME,
    @StatusID SMALLINT,
    @Priority SMALLINT

AS 

INSERT INTO DBO.Projects VALUES 
(@ProjectID,@ProjectName,GETDATE(),@Description,@EstStartDate,@EstEndDate,@StatusID,@Priority)


INSERT INTO Users_projects VALUES 
(@ProjectID,@UserID)
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear, you are trying to insert a `UserId` on the table `Users_projects` that does't exist on the table `dbo.Users`

Comment: Did you insert the User? Otherwise make sure the right column is referenced as the FK for Users table.

Comment: If you are doing mulitple inserts in one proc, you need to use explicit transactions and rollback all actions ifyou have a failure of any one statment. Otherwise you leave teh database in an incosistent state. Also use TRY catch blocks for that and return the error message in the catch block, that will help in troubleshooting later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the Foreign Key of UserID.  You need to insert UserId into the Users table first.  Few pointers:  "createProc" procedure generally should create the ProjectId and return as an OUTPUT parameter.  Also, you may want to use username as input parameter and let the proc look up the UserId.